# Dynamic-like Express routing for dynamic-object to print

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm sending an object back to express that needs to be printed via [escpos](https://www.npmjs.com/package/escpos) (for a thermal printer on Ubuntu 18).

My front end server is react.

I need to print 'receipts' for information that can be of a variety of object after the first set of variables

```
date
name
customer name
customer phone
[array of objects]
```

I can create a route for the first set of vars

```
router.post('/printer/:date/:name/:custName/:custPhone/', function(req,res,next) {
```

But is it possible to add to that route dynamically for object that can be various such as:

```
{ type: 'pizza', drinks : '2' }
```

or

```
{ extra : 'garlic bread' }
```

I current send the data back like this in the front end:

```
axios.post('/api/printer/' + newDate + '/' + userName + '/' + selectedCustomerName + '/' + selectedCustomerPhone)
```

I've considered posting such as this:

```
            axios.post('/api/printer', {
            name : userName,
            date : newDate,
            customerName : selectedCustomerName,
            customerPhone: selectedCustomerPhone,
            type : orderType,
            extra : orderExtra,
            drink : orderDrink
        })
```

and then grabbing it in Express, parsing for information and then sending to the printer seem's the most local way.

I was curious if a method with a 'dynamic' route is possible otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to set all the needed variables as route params. You should put them all in the request body like you 'considered' to do.

Then at the server:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));

router.post('/printer', function(req, res) {

  const data = req.body;
  console.log(data)

  //Do what ever you want 

  res.send('OK')

}
```